# Strange CPU usage in Xcode Activity Monitor

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-usage

This is a bit strange. When I execute the same app without changing anything in my code (just clicking "Record" in the Activity Monitor Instrument), I will get varying CPU on different runs - and it always varies by 10%.

This isn't switching back and forth in any systematic way, so my app can run at 30% CPU or 40% CPU (allowing the CPU to reach an equilibrium after a few seconds of startup).

What's causing this if nothing is changed in my code. Is it due to internal processes on the device?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Also, I don't retain any information or to my knowledge use any time varying functions (apart from the seed in some random functions...)

Comment: I take it not too many other people test their cpu? :P

Comment: Are you running this on an actual device, and not simulator?

Comment: @jsksma2 yep, username is "mobile"

Comment: That doesn't guarantee that you aren't using simulator with it named "mobile"? Anyway, @Arun is right. CPU usage varies each time because the reading you're getting isn't totally accurate.

Comment: Yeah I was curious as to why the reading deviated so systematically

Comment: I looked around, and couldn't dig up anything. If I had to guess, I would think that getting a reading through the cable that's connected to the computer would skew the numbers a bit. But again, that's a total guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think, CPU % will vary a little, for each execution.

The application should be executed for say 10 times, and the average CPU % should be considered as its actual load.

Comment: true, but here I'm seeing either one or the other, not a random distribution in a given range.